# Fusillade Throws exception "The type initializer for 'Fusillade.NetCache' threw an exception"

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using `fusillade` version 0.7.0 in a Xamarin PCL project, and receive the following error :

> "The type initializer for 'Fusillade.NetCache' threw an exception"
>   when I make a first call to an API.

This happens only in AdHoc builds. It works well in the simulator.

Comment: https://github.com/paulcbetts/Fusillade/issues/4 try to figure out the detail error message.

Comment: Thank you @ColeXia.
I fixed the problem by removing the library in the iOs project, and only keep it in the PCL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the package in the iOs project and only keep the one in the PCL did the trick.